# Logo: "Bitcoin accepted" but not "here"

Tags: bitcoin-logo

One can find lots of logos on the internet that say "Bitcoin accepted here".  In some contexts, including, but not limited to, selling things over the internet, it seems appropriate to omit that last word and just say "Bitcoin accepted".  Are there some of those?

[image: original]

Comment: Ah. More like [this](https://i.imgur.com/uL1eFvI.png), then?

Comment: I have removed some comments that were discussing whether or not the question was showing sufficient effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments on the question, here is the one that Nick ODell created:
[image: Bitcoin accepted]

And another with the accepted moved a bit to the right, I just created:
[image: Bitcoin accepted with accepted aligned to the right]

For comparison, the original:
[image: original Bitcoin accepted here]